# What exactly happens when I run python3 -i file.py

Tags: macos, python-3.x, read-eval-print-loop

Lets say `test.py` has the contents

```
i_am_a_variable = 1
i_am_also_a_var = 2

while True:
    input('> ')
```

Then, while in the same directory as `test.py`, I run `python3`. Now then, in the REPL, I execute `from test import *`. Since the Python 3 REPL has auto-completion, variables are actually also auto-completed in this infinite `input` loop. That is, when I run

```
$ python3
>>> from test import *
> i_am_a|
```

(`|` represents my cursor) If I press tab, as if my cursor is at the end of the line `i_am_a`, it will auto-complete to `i_am_a_variable`.

Now, if I run `python3 -i test.py`, this behavior does not occur. That is, the REPL will not auto-complete. So what exactly occurs when I run `python3 -i test.py`. Does `test.py` just run and then `globals` gets copied over to the REPL?

This was tested on macOS, In case auto-completion is not available on other python distributions. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python initializes autocompletion when interactive mode is entered. (If you want the details, it calls [`sys.__interactivehook__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.__interactivehook__), and one of the things the default `__interactivehook__` does is import [`rlcompleter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/rlcompleter.html) and configure TAB to trigger completion.)

When you launch Python in interactive mode and then run `from test import *` interactively, Python turns on autocompletion before it hits the `input` loop. Autocompletion isn't really intended to affect `input`, but it does anyway.

When you run `test.py` with `python3 -i`, Python doesn't enter interactive mode. It *plans* to enter interactive mode when `test.py` finishes, and it *plans* to run `sys.__interactivehook__` and turn on autocompletion when that happens, but the `input` loop happens before it reaches that point.

Comment: So if i import rlcompleter will I obtain autocompletion of global/locals in my module? - Looks like no :/ I'm just really curious as to how to have this autocompletion behavior in my module. But this does answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: Ha! Thank you so much for this answer! I tried calling `sys.__interactivehook__()` at the top of my module, after importing `sys`, and now auto-completion works on `python3 -i test.py`. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Just to clarify my comment above, I also imported rlcompleter before calling the hook.

Answer (score 0):

There is a infinite loop which is executed in your code which tries to read the standard input so it is not autocompleting the variable as the script control is in your code to read the input, not in REPL.

Lets say you `test.py`:

```
i_am_a_variable = 1
i_am_also_a_var = 2
```

without the loop, REPL executes the code(`python -i test.py`) and autocomplete works if not it won't as the REPL executes the `input` statement of the loop. The above one which you have told that autocomplete works by import in REPL wouldn't have worked, if am correct.

The final solution reproduced

```
$ cat test.py
i_am_a_variable = 1
i_am_also_a_var = 2

def Infinite():
    while True:
        input('> ')

$ python3 -i test.py
>>> Infinite()
> i_am_a
i_am_a_variable  i_am_also_a_var  
> i_am_a
i_am_a_variable  i_am_also_a_var  
> i_am_a_variable
> i_am_a
i_am_a_variable  i_am_also_a_var  
> i_am_a
i_am_a_variable  i_am_also_a_var  
> i_am_also_a_var
>
```

Comment: When I run my code in the REPL using `from test.py import *`, which executes the infinite loop, the variables *do* auto-complete. I encourage you to test it.

Comment: It wouldn't have please check.

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/JUlupNE.gif) is a GIF of a screen recording I just made. Notice that, when inside `infinite()`, auto complete *still works*.

Comment: Hi Enrico, It works when the infinite loop is inside a function with `python3 -i test.py` similar to your gif try it out.

Comment: I can't reproduce that... If I just add a call to `infinite()` at the end of `test.py` as it is on the GIF, auto complete does not work.